# Can MSBuild ignore a project reference? (BuildProjectReferences doesn't work)

Tags: msbuild, build-automation

I am trying to make a build script for a .NET solution which consists of several c# projects and one custom project. The custom project can be build by devenv but msbuild chokes on it.

I would like MSBuild to ignore the custom project because I'm already building it with an `Exec` task. I actually need MSBuild to not even open the custom .proj file because it's in JSON format and thus causes MSBuild to crash out.

The /BuildProjectReferences=false switch doesn't work. MSBuild still tries to read the custom project file. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question stemmed from a project which had a SilverFrost Fortran project alongside several c# class libraries. The solution would only compile using devenv. Msbuild would throw an error on the Fortran project because it doesn't use the standard .csproj format.

Even with /BuildProjectReferences=false, msbuild would try to read the Fortran project and throw an error. The workaround I discovered was to wrap the msbuild task in an nant task which does the following:

1. Invokes the Fortran command line compiler
2. Removes all references to the Fortran project from other .csproj projects using the `xmlpoke` task
3. Replaces said references with a direct dll reference to the Fortran compiler output
4. Invokes Msbuild on the modified solution

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building your solution once by MSBuild, try to build each project one by one. In this case, you can ignore the desired project. You can also define your own "Exec"-based build  in this new script.

Comment: The projects are inter-dependent, so MSBuild tries to open the custom project when it see it listed as a dependency in another project. Even though I've already build the dependant project with an `Exec` task, MSBuild still tries to open it so it can assert whether or not it needs to be rebuilt. I want to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

In your project that uses the custom project, can you right click on the Project Dependencies and remove the custom project from the list? You can refer to the custom project's binary output instead.